# where are Roles stored?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

I just started dabbling in to ASP.NET security. Have a few questions.
1) I used role management to restrict access to certain page. This was the section of my web.config

```
<profile>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, 
            System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
            applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, 
            Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, 
            System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This works fine. But what happened was the connecitonStringName was set to "ApplicationServices" before. And it wouldn't work. I then changed it to "LocalSqlServer". It started working.

So I want to understand, why would that happen? Also, is LocalSqlServer just another arbitrary name for the connection string value? I checked the database, the roles aren't stored there. So where are the roles stored then?

These are newbie questions. I thank your patience in advance

Comment: Further in your web.config, there should be a connection string named LocalSqlServer.  That is where the Role data would be housed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would that happen?

Using the wrong connection string would mean the membership and role tables would not be found by your application.

> Is LocalSqlServer just another arbitrary name for the connection
>   string value?

In the web.config you'll see a connection string called `LocalSqlServer`

> Where are the roles stored?

Have a look in the `aspnet_Roles` table if it's the old membership framework, or `UserProfile` if it's the newer SimpleMembershipProvider.

Comment: I just checked my app. I saw this folder \Web\App_Data This folder has the ASPNETDB.MDF and aspnetdb_log.LDF. I think this would be it, correct?

Comment: That's the database yes.

Comment: I am going to deploy them to our QA box. Right now, locally it works fine. I am going to deploy them to our QA box, hopefully that will work too. I shouldn't have to run aspnet_regsql.exe , correct?

Comment: You'll have to deploy the membership tables to your QA box yes.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you declare the `AspNetSqlProfileProvider`, you specify `connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"` to tell it which connection to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see Membership tables in your database, you should add them there. There is a special tool, which helps to do it:

Run the following command in VisualStudio command line: `aspnet_regsql`
or find it here: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe.`

And just follow its instructions.